# date variables in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, chron

I have dates that are before 1969 stored as a character and want to change them to a date column.

This is the code I've tried

```
options(chron.year.expand = 
          function (y, cut.off = 19, century = c(1900, 2000), ...) {
            chron:::year.expand(y, cut.off = cut.off, century = century, ...)
          }
)

test$construction_date2<-as.Date(chron(format(as.Date(test$construction_date,  "%d-%b-%y"),"%d/%m/%Y")))
```

But I get the warning message:

```
Warning message:
In convert.dates(dates., format = fmt, origin. = origin.) :
  224 months out of range set to NA
```

With the output:

```
construction_date     contruction_date2
23-MAR-59                  2059-03-23
05-JUN-95                  1995-06-05
30-MAY-87                  1987-05-30
15-JAN-18                  NA
01-FEB-68                  2068-02-01
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Reproducible example;

```
constuction_date<-c("23-MAR-59","05-JUN-95","30-MAY-87","15-JAN-18","01-FEB-68")
```

Expected outcome:

```
construction_date     contruction_date2
23-MAR-59                  1959-03-23
05-JUN-95                  1995-06-05
30-MAY-87                  1987-05-30
15-JAN-18                  2018-01-15
01-FEB-68                  1968-02-01
```

Comment: If you can provide a subset of your input data and the desired output for a reproducible example, it will be much easier for people here to help you. Thanks :)

Comment: @mysteRious I've added these in, Thanks :)

Comment: looks like someone already posted the `lubridate` solution... that's the package that has given me the most date success also :)

Comment: @mysteRious `dmy` function unfortunately will return `2059` and not `1959` for the `59` value. I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was that you used `as.Date` which represents ambiguous dates as post-1970 (see [here](https://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html)). Output of the vector you passed into `chron` using `as.Date`:

```
> as.Date(construction_date,"%d-%b-%y")
[1] "2059-03-23" "1995-06-05" "1987-05-30" "2018-01-15" "2068-02-01"
```

Correct way to do it was to not use `as.Date` to convert the date first but use `chron` with the `format` option directly:

```
options(chron.year.expand = 
          function (y, cut.off = 19, century = c(1900, 2000), ...) {
            chron:::year.expand(y, cut.off = cut.off, century = century, ...)
          }
)

> as.Date(chron(dates.=construction_date,format="day-month-year"))
[1] "1959-03-23" "1995-06-05" "1987-05-30" "2018-01-15" "1968-02-01"
```